# PostgreSQL "if not exists" always throws syntax error

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM information_schema.tables
   WHERE table_schema = 'topgun' AND table_name = 'session'
) 

THEN

CREATE TABLE topgun.session (
  sid varchar NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
  sess json NOT NULL,
  expire timestamp(6) NOT NULL
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE topgun.session ADD CONSTRAINT "session_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("sid") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
CREATE INDEX "IDX_session_expire" ON topgun.session ("expire");     

END IF;
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is creating a table, a constraint and an index if the table doesn't exist.

I'm getting various syntax errors even when I change empty rows. `IF NOT EXISTS` always causes an error, no matter what I do or what comes after it. As if PostgreSQL didn't even know it. Even if I copy snippets from tutorials, PostgreSQL freaks out.

I'm using Heroku Postgres, version 12.4.

The `SELECT` part in itself works. The `CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` rows also work outside of the structure.

The error message is:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"
  Position: 5
```

Comment: Does it throw the error if the body (then..body..end if) is removed? Is so, _include_
the error message in the question. If not, reconsider the title. And, after consideration and coming up with an SSCCE, and simplifying the SQL, _include_ the error message.

Comment: Added both, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for PL/pgSQL, just use the `IF NOT EXISTS` option in the CREATE TABLE part:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS topgun.session (
  sid varchar NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
  sess json NOT NULL,
  expire timestamp(6) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "session_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("sid")
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "IDX_session_expire" ON topgun.session ("expire");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `DO` statement

```
do $$
begin
IF NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM information_schema.tables
   WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = 'session'
) 

THEN

CREATE TABLE public.session (
  sid varchar NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
  sess json NOT NULL,
  expire timestamp(6) NOT NULL
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE public.session ADD CONSTRAINT "session_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("sid") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
CREATE INDEX "IDX_session_expire" ON public.session ("expire");     

END IF;
end;
$$
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2e3db8be4e5894ee782b47ace6e30c28)

Better you use this approach:

```
create table if not exists test(Id int)
```

Comment: This seems to work, but only if I put a line break between "do" and "$$" and a semicolon after the closing $$. Thanks! Anyway, what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I had to declare "LANGUAGE plpgsql" to avoid the error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE init() AS $_$
BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM information_schema.tables
   WHERE table_schema = 'topgun' AND table_name = 'session'
) 

THEN

CREATE TABLE topgun.session (
  sid varchar NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
  sess json NOT NULL,
  expire timestamp(6) NOT NULL
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE topgun.session ADD CONSTRAINT "session_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("sid") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
CREATE INDEX "IDX_session_expire" ON topgun.session ("expire");     

END IF;
END; $_$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CALL init();
```